# ERROR: need type assertion

Tags: go, tiedot

I thought I have asserted (as far as I've learnt Go), but I keep getting this error
`cannot use readBack["SomePIN"] (type interface {}) as type string in argument to c.String: need type assertion`

Here is my code (this snippet is from a Request Handler function and I'm using Echo Web framework and Tiedot NoSQL database)

```
// To get query result document, simply 
// read it [as stated in the Tiedot readme.md]
for id := range queryResult {
    readBack, err := aCollection.Read(id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if readBack["OtherID"] == otherID {
        if _, ok := readBack["SomePIN"].(string); ok {
            return c.String(http.StatusOK, readBack["SomePIN"])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asserting `readBack["SomePIN"]` as a string - *in the `if` statement*.  That doesn't make any change to `readBack["SomePIN"]`, however - it's still an interface{}.  In Go, nothing ever changes type.  Here's what will work:

```
for id := range queryResult {
    readBack, err := aCollection.Read(id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if readBack["OtherID"] == otherID {
        if somePIN, ok := readBack["SomePIN"].(string); ok {
            return c.String(http.StatusOK, somePIN)
        }
    }
}
```

You were tossing the string value from your type assertion, but you want it.  So keep it, as `somePIN`, and then use it.

Final note - using the `value, ok = interfaceVal.(type)` syntax is a good practice.  If `interfaceVal` turns out to be a non-string, you'll get `value = ""` and `ok = false`.  If you eliminate the ok value from the type assertion and interfaceVal is a non-string, the program will panic.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your converting to a concrete type and throwing away the conversion, I think this should work:

```
    if somePinString, ok := readBack["SomePIN"].(string); ok {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, somePinString)
    }
```